# Mount host dir into docker container without volume?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is mounting (--mount or -v) a host directory or host volume into a container only possible if the image defines a volume?

I tried to do

```
docker run -d -v maven-m2-repo:/root/.m2 maven:3-jdk-8-alpine SOME-MAVEN-PROJECT-RUN
```

as described in https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven in order to preserve Maven repository directory between container runs, but nothing gets ever written into my volume or host directory.

The Dockerfile doesn't define any volumes:

```
docker image inspect 08790c3343de
...
"ContainerConfig": {
  ...
  "Volumes": null,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create bind mount with `-v`, you need to provide absolute path `-v /path/to/maven-m2-repo:/root/.m2` or relative path `-v ./maven-m2-repo:/root/.m2`, otherwise docker treats them as volume names.

Comment: Yes, I know, I tried with a volumes but also with an absolute path. I will update my question.